# geolocalisation is very slow

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I've a application for the geolocalisation and I retrieve the current geoposition but the display on the application is VERY slow...

The constructor :

```
        public TaskGeo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _geolocator = new Geolocator();
            _geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            _geolocator.MovementThreshold = 100;
            _geolocator.PositionChanged += _geolocator_PositionChanged;
            _geolocator.StatusChanged += _geolocator_StatusChanged;

            if (_geolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
                this.DisplayNeedGPS();
        }
```

the code for the display on the app :

```
    void _geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // saving and display of the position
        App.RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this._CurrentPosition = args.Position;
            this.lblLon.Text = "Lon: " + this._CurrentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude;
            this.lblLat.Text = "Lat: " + this._CurrentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude;
            this.LocationChanged(this._CurrentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude, this._CurrentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude);
        }); 
    }
```

And the code for the query :

```
    private void LocationChanged(double lat, double lon)
    {
        ReverseGeocodeQuery rgq = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
        rgq.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);
        rgq.QueryCompleted += rgq_QueryCompleted;
        rgq.QueryAsync();
    }
```

How can I improve the code to display faster the position ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting this sort of information is basically pretty slow. To quote the great Louis C. K. "It is going to space, give it a second". Because you've specified `PositionAccuracy.High` this means that the location must be found using GPS, which is comparatively slow, and not any of the faster fallback methods such as using local wi-fi or cell phone towers.

You could reduce your demands for accuracy overall or initially request a lower accuracy and then refine it once the information from the GPS is available. The second option is better. If you look at a map application they typically do this by showing you about where you are and then improving it after the GPS lock is acquired.

Comment: I think Stimms is right. We always have to compensate accuracy with speed. Give it a try by reducing accuracy. Let us know if it is getting better. Performing geolocation using IP address is faster than GPS or wifi.